# How to log in a background task and avoid async state corruption

Tags: nlog

Using Nlog.Web.AspNetCore 4.7.0 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1

I have some background tasks, such as sending email, and basically I don't wait for the result to complete. I use logging with NLog to log the result of these tasks.

After a log entry is done in a background task, the next request loses it's HTTP Method, and then returns 404, because there is no route responding to requests without a HTTP Method.

According to Microsoft, accessing HttpContext in a background thread is not safe, and can cause async state corruption, causing this problem.
See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4195.

So my question is, is there a safe way to use Nlog in a background task? Can I change something?

Answer (score 0):

NLog gives a lot of attention to async logging. The standard NLog Layouts performs capture of current context state to allow async logging.

By default all NLog layoutrenderers will perform capture of current context-state when a logevent is registered.

Only "optimized" layoutrenderers that doesn't depend on the current context-state will allow one to skip the overhead from this capture.

Instead of trying to create your own background task, then you should just enable `<targets async="true">` and perform the logging while the HttpContext is active.

The NLog Mail-Target (Or Mailkit-Target) should out of the box capture the required HttpContext-state upfront, so they can send mails in the background. If not then it is a bug that should be reported to the NLog-project: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks, I think my question is different. I have a background task, and from that task I want to do some logging. I understand your remark about logging asynchronously

Comment: Basically, I think I should capture the HttpContext state and provide it to the Logger when loging.

Comment: If you need to do some actually background report (ex generate report from request). Then you need to manually capture what you need from the HttpContext and forward to NLog when ready to do some logging.

Comment: Hi Rolf, I want to send a mail without waiting for the mail to be sent. But in case it goes wrong, I want to log the error. Nlog than access the HttpContext, but it seams to corrupt the async state. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4195

Comment: This was the conclusion there: Background threads cannot safely access HttpContext. Since logging can sometimes happen on background threads it also cannot access HttpContext. If you really want to log something like the method then pass that value through as a paramter, don't try to read it from ambient thread context.

Comment: You can use the NLog FallbackGroup https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target . Where it tries the Mail-Target first and when it fails then writes to some other NLog-Target (Ex. LogFile). Again just use `<targets async="true">` as NLog gives a lot of attention to async logging (Ofcourse without starting your own background task)

Comment: mm, I want to write an email to a customer, not logging something to the mail target. My point is, I am starting my own background task, and should be able to provide the original HTTPContext, to Nlog, or prevent it from using it

Comment: Btw. if using async task in the background, then the NLog MDLC should be available from the original request. It contains values like "RequestId" + "RequestPath" + "CorrelationId". You can use BeginScope to add your own context-values to NLog MDLC

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not hold a direct reference to HttpContext. Access it via an instance of HttpContextAccessor instead:

```
protected IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

// _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.XYProperty
```

Comment: Think Microsoft has put extra effort into avoiding that background tasks can access the HttpContext after the request has completed. So while the background task can (when lucky) access the HttpContext while the request is still active, then it might experience that HttpContext has become inaccessible at a later stage. So I think the advice is to capture what you need from the HttpContext before launching the background task, instead of relying on being lucky.

Comment: One option is to store state in NLog MDLC for async use (Or setup own `AsyncLocal`-variable to capture individual properties). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer